# How to solve "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in a loop routine

Tags: ajax, post, dynamic

Googled all similar questions here, but no useful answer. I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" while trying to pass some data to an update.php file using ajax.

My code (php) is getting data from a SELECT (MySQL) and builds tables *while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)*. Inside each dynamically generated table I put an editing field for each row of result, so that user can look at the result data, input some side notes and save them. To make long story short, when user clicks on an icon in a table, the click calls the updateNotes() function, where I use ajax to pass to update.php file the notes written by the user. Cut away all the complex nested dynamic structure of the tables built, I put hereafter the part of the code (simplified without dynamic variables and nesting) with the actual ajax part.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
// get all data from a SELECT and "while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)" I set $count to a number that increases for each row of result
//then show some things
//let's say that every table has a suffix "_n" for all its elements, where "n" is the value of $count
// to focus on my issue, hereafter I don't put the dynamic generation of names, but simply will use the suffix "_n"

echo "<form method='post' id='form_edit_n' name='form_edit_n' action='update.php'>";
    // echo some data from the SELECT query
    // also echo some hidden data from the SELECT query, among them there's "type_a_data_n" hidden field (same id and name)
    echo "<img src='showEditorField.png' id='showEditorField_n' name='showEditorField_n' onclick='editor_n()'/>";
    // to have a different editing field for each recurrence found with the SELECT
echo "</form>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

// do some things non relevant as far as my issue is concerned, such as show and hide icons and fields
// among the rest, the function "editor_n()" shows an input field dynamically named let's say 'note_n'
// "editor_n()" also shows the icon "iconEditConfirm.png" with id and name "iconEditConfirm", that has "onclick='updateNotes()'"
// file update.php listens for $_POST["data_type_a"] and $_POST["note"]
// now the following is the function updateNotes()

function updateNotes() {
    var note_x = 'note_n';
    var type_a_data_x = 'type_a_data_n';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {'data_type_a': type_a_data_x, 'note': note_x},
        success:function(){
            // here I don't know how to get the return from update.php
        }
    });
}

// and this is the update.php code

<?php 

// make a connection to db, result is $conn

$note = $_POST["note"];
$data_type_a = $_POST["data_type_a"];

$sqlupdatenote = "UPDATE table SET note='$note' WHERE column='$data_type_a'";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlupdatenote)) {
    echo "Updated note";
    return;
} else {
    echo "Error updating";
    return;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

How can I fix the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" issue?
Also, is it correct to pass data to the js vars using the above syntax?

Just an update: looking at the net analysis in Firebug, jQuery isn't loaded, despite the link is the right one.

Answer (score -1):

$ is not defined means you missed a reference to your jquery library.This CDN link will help you
""